# How to get Output of any project on button click event

Tags: java, swing

I am working on Jframe Form in NetBeans. Actually my problem is .........
I have a List, button, Textbox and a TextArea. In list, there are many projects(like Update, Sum).
When I select a project from the list, The input of this list will be shown in Textbox(like Update.jar , Sum.jar) . When I execute jar file, the output of jar file should be shown in TextArea. How can I do that . Anyone Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

 try{
 String a= String.valueOf(jList1.getSelectedValue());

jTextArea1.setText(String.valueOf(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "+ a+".jar")));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
    }                                        
}
```

Code of Sum.jar

```
 package sum;

 public class Sum {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 int a=10,b=90;

 int s=a+b;

 System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:"+s);    

 }
}
```

Comment: what does "output of this project" actually mean? are you talking about executing *.jar files?

Comment: You should try to edit your question, it is unclear what your actual problem is

Comment: @eis  when I execute jar file of "sum" project in command prompt, then I get an output "sum of two number is 100". But I want to this output in jTextArea.

Comment: Have you tried declaring your sum public in the main class so the other projects can access it?

Comment: But I am using many jar files of many java codes. Normally I want to output of jar files in jTextArea when I click on button

Comment: My project and all jar files of projects are in same folder

Comment: make your jar files write into a text file, and make the other jar files read the text file??? I bet there is an easier way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should post the code of the class with the `JTextArea`, if not we can't probably see where your mistake is

Comment: that is, if you've tried yet.

Comment: Is the program working as you expect if you run it from your IDE?

Comment: @Mine Actually I have two jar files sum.jar and Update.jar. I am accessing these two in my project. I want to execute these jar file on button click event and get output in JtextArea

Comment: I dont understand your problem? If you simply want to execute stand alone jar files use a `ProcessBuilder` and read its output. If you want to execute methods from within a jar file you need to use a custom classloader and some reflection.

Comment: @ArcticLord, How can I use ProcessBuilder. Please tell me in detail

Comment: Someone actually upvoted this? :/

Comment: I did, @eis he is a new user and probably does not know how this site works, so I'm trying my best to help him because this site is incredibly hostile towards new users.

Comment: @MineRockers I don't think it's about this site - the question is of quite low quality, and would be so in any site I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do. This method runs a jar file and return its output.

```
public String getOutputOf(String jarfile) throws IOException{
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder ("java", "-jar",  jarfile); 
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true); 
    Process process = builder.start();             
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much @ArcticLord

Answer (score 1):

I'll try my best to answer you.

So you want to execute the two jar files, "Sum.jar" and "Update.jar", and get their output and put in a JTextArea?

Well, there is two parts to your solution.

First, you can launch jar files from clicking a button by using the Desktop API.

For example,

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(yourfilename));
```

That was the launching files from button code.

For "Sum.jar" and "Update.jar", you can make it so that on action, they will calculate what ever you want them to calculate, and output the output in a text file.

For Example:

```
FileWriter fileWriter;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter("Output.txt");
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferedWriter.write(yourOutput);
            bufferedWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
```

Then, you can have the JTextArea scan the text file and output it into the JTextArea.

For Example:

```
        try {
String content = new Scanner(new File("Output.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
jTextArea.setText(content);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
        }
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: Did my explanation and code examples help you solve your problem @abcd

Comment: I am trying to do this. Thanks

Comment: Also, could you please share your code for "Sum.jar" and "Update.jar"? It would make it easier for me to help you.

Comment: Error:Invalid or Corrupt jarfile

Comment: Then that it the problem of your jar file, could you share the corrupt jar file's code?

Comment: package sum;
public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int a=10,b=90;
        int s=a+b;
        System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:"+s);
        
    }
}

Comment: package sum;
public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int a=10,b=90;
        int s=a+b;
        System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:"+s);
        
    }
}

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                    
 try{
  String a= String.valueOf(jList1.getSelectedValue());
   ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder ("java", "-jar",  a+".jar"); 
   builder.redirectErrorStream(true); 
   Process process = builder.start();         
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    jTextArea1.setText(sb.toString());
    }
   catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
   }                                        
  }
```